# Symfony cache:clear problem: No session available

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfony-cache

The problem is very simple. The applications works as expected, no problems, sessions work, etc.
But when I try to clear the cache:

```
bin/console c:c
// Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                                          

In RequestStack.php line 105:
                                            
  There is currently no session available.
```

Any ideas?

Symfony version 6, all the latest packages.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand how clearing the cache is dependent on a session being available or where to start to look for the problem.

Comment: try `bin/console c:c -vvv` and you will get more information

Comment: Have you create a subscriber a with KernelEvents::REQUEST ? it passes at the same time as Session was creating.
change your event priorities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in one of the Services, trying to call

```
requestStack->getSession()
```

in the `__construct` method.

The key to finding this error was to get a stack trace, using the `bin/console c:c -vvv`